# Java: trouble with i++

Tags: java, while-loop, compare

I am having trouble with getting why a part of code even runs:

```
private int m;
private int n;

public void f() {
    m = (m +2) % n;
    System.out.print(m+"\n");
}

public void g() {
    int i=0;
    m=0;
    n=8;
    while (i++<n) {
        System.out.print("i=" + i + " m=");
        f();
    }
}
```

If I run `g()`, I get the following printed out:

```
i++=1 m=2
i++=2 m=4
i++=3 m=6
i++=4 m=0
i++=5 m=2
i++=6 m=4
i++=7 m=6
i++=8 m=0
```

As I understand it, the last line shouldn't appear. Why does `f()` get that last time?

When `f()` gets called the first time, `i = 0` and there for `i++ = 1`. (so when I print `i`, it is already equal to `1`).

When I call `f()` the second to last time, `i = 6`, and there for `i++ = 7`. That is the last entire which is `< n` ( `n = 8` ).

Why does the function get again called, when `i++` is already `= 8`? this really confuses me.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `i++` and `++i`? If not, research that, then you know why your code works like that.

Comment: How is it possible to receive such output? Cannot reproduce!

Comment: @xenteros http://ideone.com/jr9QDr

Comment: @xenteros just change the print statement to: System.out.print("i++= " + i + " m=")

Comment: @xenteros OP just missed the "++" in his output String. The changed one from the comment fixes that. And I guess your second problem is the hardcoded `\n` and when you're on Windows, it might doesn't show a "real" line break.

Comment: In this case it didn't matter, but on [so] we often face a problem of not real output so the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: @xenteros Even though you're generally correct, this isn't the case here. The output is logically correct and can be reproduced.

Comment: @Tom don't worry, didn't flag that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `++i` instead of `i++`.

This has to do with the fact that:

- `++i` means "increment `i` and return the resulting number to the next operator to process." (PRE-increment)
- `i++` means "return the value of i to the next operation, and increment `i` AFTER you do so." (POST-increment)

Comment: In many coding styles, it's bad practice to use `++` inside statements, as it creates confusion. (Notable exception may be array iteration with `array[i++]`)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of mixing up increment and compare at all either.  Especially when parens would mask the difference too (if the i++ were in parens, the OP wouldn't have noticed).  I get why C-like languages have this (often there is an assembly construct that's not far off), but yuck.

Answer (score 3):

Use `++i` instead of `i++`.

- i++ makes a copy, increases i, and returns the copy, so it will
  return the old value of i (Post Increment).
- ++i increases i, and returns i, the updated value(Pre increment).

So when you check the condition `i++<n` it is checked with the old value, so the condition is evaluated to true.

Answer (score 2):

This is because i++ is post increment. That meens that it is incremented after the compare to n. You must use ++i if you want to increment i before the compare to n

Answer (score 2):

When you have:

```
while(i++<n){
...
}
```

It's as if you would have:

```
while(i<n){
i++;
...
}
```

The value first gets used, and THEN incremented.

If you want the value to first be incremented and then used in evaluation of the condition, you would just use this:

```
while(++i<n){
...
}
```

Note, that this is true not only with while, but also with if, for, do-while and any other inline evaluation of your variable.

Comment: Can you describe what's the difference, then?